# SQL Server why isn't there an implicit conversion when comparing bit and a literal?

Tags: sql-server, types, literals

I  know that if you are comparing two different types, sql has to convert whatever side has the lowest type precedence to match the other type. For example, where varchar = nvarchar in this case if the left-hand side is a column on a table, the entire set has to be converted to nvarchar before doing the comparison.

If we follow the same pattern, having "where Bit_Column = 1", SQL would have to first convert the bit column to integer right? But when I look at the Execution plan, SQL converted the literal to bit and not the other way around.

Why is this happening?

thanks

Comment: I'm honestly not sure I understand the question, or why you would imagine it would be otherwise. The conversion of a literal 1 to bit (or even "yes" or "no" to bit) is straightforward and expected. In your string case, it's converted to nvarchar because converting the other way could result in loss of data, so it's not allowed without a specific cast.

Comment: Please show us where in an execution plan you saw a literal converted to a bit.  Also, literal isn't a data type, integer and bit are.

Comment: I'd imagine the query optimizer was just converting the int to a bit instead of the opposite as it's more efficient. Why convert every bit in the `Bit_Column` to int when you can just convert a single integer 1 to a bit?

Answer (score 0):

There are Bit constants in SQL Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql

It seems that 1 is interpreted as BIT constant in your query.
Unfortunately I can't find what is difference between bit and integer constant.